# How to access subcclass attributes in super class methods, without passing them in

Tags: python, django, django-admin, superclass

How does one access a derived class'es property (static variable in other languages), in its base classes method?
I.e.

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def get_list(cls):
        return [1, 2, cls.x]

class Derived(Base):
    x = 3
    foo = Base.get_list()    

Derived.foo # Hope to have it set to [1, 2, 3]
```

I wish to not pass x directly to the base class, i.e. `foo = Base.get_list(x)` because I have a lot of methods to be called with the same variables.

### EDIT

The comments have asked for context. I tried to make a minimum reproducible example to spare you guys the details.

Here's the full context: So its actually to do with Django Admin.
I have a abstract model. Then I have various admin interfaces for the various concrete implementation of the abstract model. As you can guess I created an abstract admin model to handle the common logic. A part of handling the common admin logic, e.g. generating properties on the derived admin model.

So for example the list display, here's the logic to create the list display:

```
class FactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    @classmethod
    def build_list_display(cls, *custom):
        return (
            'created_utc',
            *custom,
            'foo__bar__abbreviation',
            'foo__baz__name',
            'foo__caz__name',
            'foo__daz__description',
            'foo__eaz__code',
        )

@admin.register(FooEntry)
class FoopEntryAdmin(FactAdmin):
    fieldsets = FactAdmin.build_list_display('cannon_ball', 'pogo_stick')
```

So in the base admin class, it keeps reusing a list of custom fields, custom models, and other things. So instead of passing them in each time, for each property, it seemed more DRY to set them as static attributes.  Hence I wished to set them as static member fields on the derived class, and access them in the base class.

Comment: You usually shouldn't do that. What if there's a subclass that doesn't have that attribute?

Comment: Also, at the time you're calling `Base.set_foo()`, the `Super` class hasn't even been created yet.

Comment: Your question is unclear and ambiguous for me, please Insert more explanation of what you want beside the problem you're facing.

Comment: Why not just set Base.x = 3 instead of x=3 inside class Super?

Comment: @LevB I guess for different subclasses to have different values

Comment: @das-g sorry, I standardised on base/derived naming convention.

Comment: `set_foo()` is a misleading name for something thatdoesn't set anything, it just returns a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing subclass attributes in a superclass classmethod called on the subclass isn't a problem. This works as expected:

```py
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def get_list(cls):
        return [1, 2, cls.x]


class Derived(Base):
    x = 3


assert Derived.get_list() == [1, 2, 3]
```

However, you can't easily call that classmethod right in the subclass's class body, as at that time, the class object for `Derived` and indeed the name `Derived` don't exist yet. (You could call it in methods, classmethods and staticmathods, because their body is evaluated when they are invoked, and not already when they are defined. But that doesn't help here.) And if called on `Base`, it obviously lacks `x`. (And being a Python classmethod, `get_list` has to be explicitly called on something. We can't just make an unqualified call as in Java.)

So

```py
class Derived(Base):
    x = 3
    foo = get_list()
```

results in `NameError: name 'get_list' is not defined`,

```py
class Derived(Base):
    x = 3
    foo = Base.get_list()
```

results in `AttributeError: type object 'Base' has no attribute 'x'` and

```py
class Derived(Base):
    x = 3
    foo = Derived.get_list()
```

results in `NameError: name 'Derived' is not defined`.

But all is not lost. Let's not forget that Python allows us to create and set class attributes from outside the class. So this works:

```py
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def get_list(cls):
        return [1, 2, cls.x]


class Derived(Base):
    x = 3


Derived.foo = Derived.get_list()


assert Derived.foo == [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Wow really indepth answer, thank you so much! That is really clever at the end to set the class attributes from outside the class! This is a concept I have worked around for a few years now because did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using class attributes and methods.  You should be defining classes that you create instances of, and use instance methods and attributes, so that normal inheritance works the way it was intended to be used in the language.

Then you need to take advantage of the fact that instance methods can be overridden by subclasses.  Here, to let the parent class get at the child class's `x`, you define a `get_x` method in the parent class that you expect to have overridden in the child class.  That's how the child class's `x` gets used by the parent without it ever being passed to it.

Here's an example:

```
class Base:
    def set_foo(self):
        return [1, 2, self.get_x()]

    def get_x(self):
        return 0

class Sub(Base):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 3
        self.foo = super().set_foo()

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

print(Sub().foo)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you this is a good concept to keep in mind, that methods can be used like properties before the initialiser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want super to access the property of a derived class, it's probably because this property is shared by all derived subclasses (you don't make any check on the derived class type anyway). In such case, the most logical thing to do is to implement the property in super instead, and that solves the problem :

```
class Base:
    x = 3
    @classmethod
    def get_foo():
        return [1, 2, self.x]
```